# I can't get a input from user as float in java

Tags: java, input, java-7

I am just try to get a input as float but, I got an error. Please, help me to fix it.

**This is my code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Input
        int a = in.nextInt();  // Integer
        String b = in.nextLine();  // String
        Float c = in.nextFloat();  // Float
        
        // Output
        System.out.println("Given integer :"+a);
        System.out.println("Given string :"+b);
        System.out.println("Given Float :"+c);
    }
}
```

**This is Output**

```
2 
stack 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) 
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) 
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345) 
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have any whitespace character as a seperator just use `next()` for reading a `String`:

```
// Input
int a = in.nextInt();  // Integer
String b = in.next();  // String
float c = in.nextFloat();  // float
```

This will accept all input values in one line or with line breaks

```
123 abc 456.789
Given integer :123
Given string :abc
Given Float :456.789
```

or

```
123
abc
456.789
Given integer :123
Given string :abc
Given Float :456.789
```

If you aim to have only line breaks as input separator use the solution suggested by @marc:

```
// Input
int a = in.nextInt();  // Integer
in.nextLine();
String b = in.nextLine();  // String
float c = in.nextFloat();  // float
```

output will be:

```
123
abc
456.789
Given integer :123
Given string :abc
Given Float :456.789
```

and consequent expressions in the same line will be ignored:

```
123 abc 4.5
def
6.7
Given integer :123
Given string :def
Given Float :6.7
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt()` does not read the new line character (when you click return). You need an additional `nextLine()` Try with:

```java
int a = in.nextInt();  // Integer
in.nextLine();
String b = in.nextLine();  // String
Float c = in.nextFloat();  // Float
```

Answer (score 0):

javadoc of nextline says

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the inputthat was skipped.This >method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any lineseparator at the end. The >position is set to the beginning of the nextline.
> Since this method continues to search through the input lookingfor a line separator, it >may buffer all of the input searching forthe line to skip if no line separators are >present.

Advancing the line causes that in.nextFloat tries to read and parse "stack".
This will become visible if you write only numbers in the console

i recommend to read strings with next() instead of nextLine()